# Indoor location SDK with map drawing

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, beacon, indoor-positioning-system

I need to develop a PoC, where I can draw an office in some tool, and then with beacons or something else that each person has in its pocket, to know in realtime where the people are, maybe a heatmap to know where people stands for more time.

I do have experience in C#, nodejs, js, typescript, so is there any SDK out there that I can easily reuse for this?

Comment: Sounds like you have an interest in an Indoor Positioning System.
I am unaware of any open libraries, but there are several companies working on this.
This is one example: http://www.indooratlas.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Estimote "Long Range Location Beacons" (and only those) support indoor positioning with maps, but only for iOS at the time.
Have a look: http://estimote.com/indoor/

Heatmaps (for how long is a person standing at beacon X) should be possible with every kind of beacon.

Answer (score 0):

There's two potential ways to do this: 1) Have scanners installed in the premises and put some small tracker devices on the people you want to track or 2) Utilize the people's mobile phones and some mobile positioning system.

Option 2 is generally cheaper and easier, so would recommend that. There are couple of technologies you can use for the positioning, such as IndoorAtlas that was already mentioned or Bluetooth beacons. If you're looking for an easy solution, check out Proximi.io (Disclaimer: I work for them). It's a unified positioning platform, free for small projects.